# Obtaining parent size to use within child

Tags: flutter

I am trying to put an AnimatedContainer inside my Expanded widget (since having the AnimatedContainer as the parent throws Flex errors), as I am using an event to resize two Expanded containers on three possible conditions. Both start off at 50/50 flex size, then on the second condition it changes to 25/75, the last condition it's 75/25. It worked well without the Animated container, but the size transition is instant and I would prefer to have it animate.

This is essentially how things are setup at the moment:

```dart
  Flex(
    direction: Axis.horizontal,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(  // <---  I would like to get the current width of this
        flex: (target[expController.target]["newsWidth"]),
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          width: ?, // <-- and use it here
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: NewsMainHome(),
        ),
      ),
      Spacer(flex: target[expController.target]["spacer"]),
      Expanded(
        flex: (target[expController.target]["changeLogWidth"]),
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          width: ?, // Set to parent size
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: ChangeLogList(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

It would be nice to be able to set the AnimatedContainer width to the size of the parent Expanded width so it will animate the size transition when the Expanded flex value changes from the event, but I have yet to find a decent way to go about it. Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks,
-MH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LayoutBuilder`

```
Expanded(
  flex: (target[expController.target]["changeLogWidth"]),
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) => AnimatedContainer(
      width: constraints.maxWidth,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      child: ChangeLogList(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Or even simpler try this

```
Expanded(
  flex: (target[expController.target]["changeLogWidth"]),
  child: AnimatedContainer(
    width: double.infinity,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    child: ChangeLogList(),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Frederick, I tried a few variations of what you mentioned, as well as the reply from Shawn, but unfortunately none of them worked out well for me in this situation. What did end up working out was actually just removing the Expanded boxes and associated Flex container all together and using just the AnimatedContainer. Then taking the Expansion Controller and using that for the AnimatedContainer width instead of the flex. Now things are working well. https://i.imgur.com/mM2S5Uv.gifv I appreciate you guys taking the time to assist.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, use the LayoutBUilder to obtain size. For this use case though, you could just animate the Flex directly:

```
var leftFlex = 75;
return TweenAnimationBuilder<int>(
  tween: Tween(begin: 50, end: leftFlex),
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
  builder: (_, value, __){
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(flex: value, child: leftContent),
        Expanded(flex: 100 - value, child: rightContent),
      ],
    )
  },
)
```